# How to execute two MySQL queries?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I want to save the file path of a picture, AND the image name, in the same table, but separate fields of course. How can I execute it properly? I'm sure there is something significantly wrong in the code below, but I can't spot it. Thank you.

```
$sess_userid = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['userid']);
$Image = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['file']['name']);
$PortraitPath = mysql_real_escape_string('profileportraits/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);

$query  = "UPDATE Members 
             SET PortraitPath = '$PortraitPath' 
           WHERE fldID='$sess_userid'";

$query2 = "UPDATE Members 
              SET Image = '$Image' 
            WHERE fldID='$sess_userid'";  

$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$query);
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$query2);
```

Comment: How does this code fail to run?

Comment: newer versions of PHP ships with the MySQL Improved Extension (mysqli) where you can run multiple queries, but alas few CMSes uses it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can update multiple fields in the same table at the same time.

```
 $query  = "UPDATE Members 
            SET PortraitPath = '$PortraitPath',
                Image = '$Image'
            WHERE fldID='$sess_userid'"; 


mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$query);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a comma like this:

```
UPDATE Members 
   SET PortraitPath = '$PortraitPath', 
       Image = '$Image' 
 WHERE fldID = '$sess_userid'
```